# Why do I get these memory addresses?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I was wondering why I get these memory addresses in this simple program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *a = "buffera";
    char *b = "bufferbb";

    printf("%p %p\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Output I get is.

```
00403064 0040306C
```

Supposedly each character occupies one byte in memory (two hex numbers), then if the string `a` occupy 7 + 1 = 8 bytes in memory and the address of `a` starts at 0x00403064, then according to me it should end at 0x00403079 and not at 0x0040306B.

Comment: why doe you think b will start right after a?

Answer (score 4):

0043064 + 8 = 0040306C; I don't know where you get 00403079 from.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that b might not necessarily be put in memory right after a. In this case, it looks like it is, but you shouldn't assume it.

Comment: 1 byte = 1 in Hex?, but 1 Hex represent a nibble... half of a byte, then shouldn't 1 character occupy from 0x00 to 0x01, 2 charachters from 0x00 to 0x03 and so on?.

Comment: @icemanind: true, but it is more likely than any other *particular* location.

Comment: @cursillosonline: No. `sizeof(char) == 1`. So `char[1]` occupies `[0x00, 0x01)`. And `char[2]` occupies `[0x00, 0x02)`.

Comment: Hex doesn't represent anything. Its a method of counting. You can count nibbles in hex, bytes in hex, words in hex, or the number of stars in the sky in hex. Size is irrelevant

Comment: @cursillonline: Hex is just another way to represent numbers; 1 in hex means the same as 1 in octal, binary, or any other base.  A character takes 1 byte, no matter how you choose to represent the values 1.

Comment: @cursillosonline: You're confusing the address for the data. Let's give a real world example: a mail address is 4 lines long. So a single line is 1/4 of an address. So according to your logic "The White House" is 1/4 of a building.

Comment: Then a specific memory address represents an entire byte?.

Comment: @cursillosonline: Yes, and no, it depends on the architecture. Some CPU's don't have byte addressable memory so one address represents 32 or 64 bits of data. But on disk yes, one address always corresponds to one byte.

Answer (score 1):

```
0x00403064 + 0x8 == 0x0040306C
```

Note that these numbers are in hexadecimal.

But either way, while these strings can't overlap, they don't need to be placed anywhere near each other in memory.